# Newly Promoted Infopath field not appearing in form library in SharePoint 2013 On Prem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath, forms-services, sharepoint-library

I have a infopath form set to primary content type to the Form library which is working fine. The form is managed in the Central Admin.

When we create the field and promote to the library(both while publishing and Tools->Form options ->Property Promotion) and upload the form in Central Admin. 
The field is not getting promoted .Field in not appearing in the List settings page and List View Page.

Please confirm whether any settings/changes needs to be done while promoting the field.

Answer (score 0):

Please troubleshot your issue as following:

1. Whether there is any other content type in your list? Check if the field add to another content type.
2. Edit the current view, check if the promoted field is selected in columns section.
3. Create a new form and form library, check if the issue exists.